# Bootstrap Nested Column Grid Not Working Responsively

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement this grid system in boostrap but i am failed to achieve it . This is what i am trying to implement

[image]

but divs are overlapping  each other like this

[image]

this is my code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="col-md-12 colHeight topSpace">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">

            </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="posRel">

                <p class="col-centered">
                        <Button class="button-0 red" onClick="hintWord()">Hint</Button>
                        </p>
            </div>
    </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 text-center">

                <div class="imageArea">
            <div class="imageError">It is Working<img src="images/new.png"></div>
            <div class="imageSuccess"><img src="images/test.png"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>
                    </div>  

        </div>
        </div>
```

I have given 1300px height to the wrapper so the footer will not overlap with my content.

Everything is working in the full screen mode. When I check in the responsive mode the divs are overlapping  each other.

this is my css

```
#wrapper{
height:1300px;
}

.col-centered{

margin: 0 auto

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="posRel">

                    <p class="col-centered">
                        <Button class="button-0 red" onClick="hintWord()">Hint</Button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                <div class="imageArea">
                    <div class="imageError">It is Working<img src="images/new.png"></div>
                    <div class="imageSuccess"><img src="images/test.png"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```